# Export SELECT with WHERE as INSERTs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to make a set of `insert` statements from the result of a `select`.

I've found similar questions on SO, however as far as I can see, they all consider making a full export of a table, but I need to run a particular query with `where` conditions, say

```
select * from T where open_time > '2013-11-01 00:00:00'
```

**UPD**: I need to have a script as an output, because later I will insert these rows into separate DB.

Comment: new table or existing table?

Comment: @mr_eclair please see UPD

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Destination_Table (Column1, Column2, Column3, .....)
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, ..
FROM TABLE_Name   --<-- Source Table Name
WHERE Condition...    --<--- any conditions or Filters here
```

The number of Columns and DataTypes in `INSERT`  and `SELECT` statement should match

If the destination Tables doesnt exist you can create a table on fly by doing this

**Create a table on fly**

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, ..     INTO   New_Table_Name 
FROM TABLE_Name   --<-- Source Table Name
WHERE Condition...    --<--- any conditions or Filters here
```

**warning **
if a table by the name New_Table_Name  already exists then you will have to use the `INSERT INTO` Method since using the `SELECT INTO` syntax will throw an error in that case

Comment: well if the column names and datatypes are the same you can use it anywhere.

Comment: But databases are on different servers, not connected to each other

Comment: in this case you will need to add the destination Server as a Linked Server to your source server and then use the fully qualified names for tables [ServerName].[Database].[Schema].[Table]

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible. Can I generate a script as an output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

select @sql = @sql + 'insert into table1(column1, column2) values (' 
    + T.column1 + ',' + T.column2 + '); ' 
from T where open_time > '2013-11-01 00:00:00'

print (@sql)
```

This will generate insert statements you can copy and use later.

You may have to modify it as depending on the data types you may need quotes and formatting for the columns returned from `T`.

Comment: how can I not specify names of columns? I need to select all of them

Comment: Just do `insert into table1 values ...`

Comment: but how about `values`. In your script you use their name explicitly. T.column1, ....

Comment: You have to as you need to actually write them one by one to match the insert syntax.

Comment: it's not as simple, i had to do that in the past too at the fly with random table. You have to manage if it's a number or another type, depending of the type you should add ' before and after your value. You have to play a lot with information_schema to have these information. If it's an operation you are doing manual, install something like ssms tools pack (free before 2012) and right click on table to generate an insert and copy past your where clause in the appropriate textbox

Comment: Yes, it's doable in more simple cases though. As long as you don't try to make it into some generic tool.

Answer (score 0):

select into can help you

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName, Phone
INTO dbo.PhoneList492
FROM Person.Contact
WHERE Phone LIKE '492%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace column names with the columns of your table.

```
INSERT INTO NEW_T (Column1, Column2, Column2, ...)
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, ...
FROM T
WHERE open_time > '2013-11-01 00:00:00'
```

I am assuming you already have created the new table **NEW_T**.